# How to sort a django query with a specific value?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a model like this in Django:

```
 class Session(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        session_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        server_full_path = models.CharField(max_length=254)      # Contains server
        server_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)           #Server Name or IP
        file_path = models.CharField(max_length=254)             #full file path
        source_username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        source_password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        make_default = models.BooleanField()
```

I am using this query to get all the server_id:

```
all_server_id = Session.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
```

I want to the query to be sorted in a such a way that the value with make_default=1 will come at first. I want this to show in the template. How can I do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you want. It seems that you want to order by `make_default`, but at the same time you want to display all of this on a template, you want the for loop to loop in a manner that retains this order, and I correct?

Comment: Yes. But when I do for loop I want to show data with make_default = 1 at first.

Comment: Then the first answer will do that for you. Try it out.

Comment: How can it not work? Try using this this `all_server_id = Session.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).order_by('-make_default')`. And isn't `make_default` a booleanfield?

Comment: Yes, it is a boolean field and after putting '-', it worked. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is this:

```
all_server_id = Session.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).order_by('-make_default')
```

I believe that answers your question from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a query, you should use order_by() function, ex:

```
all_server_id = Session.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).order_by('make_default')
```